# why the space between my html buttons github and facebook or facebook and linkden are operating as links

Tags: html

```
<div class="links">
  <button id="writings">Writings</button>
  <button id="track">Track</button>
  <a href="https://github.com/Luffy01017" target="_blank">
    <button id="github">Github</button>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <button id="twitter">facebook</button>
  </a>
  <button id="linkden" onclick="linkden()">Linkden</button>
  <button id="email" onclick="email()">Email</button>
</div>
```

i was expecting the space between them to be just a blank space but whenever i click the cursor on the space between buttons the buttons it acts as a link

Comment: The space is entirely within the div that you classed as "links". Not sure what you mean by "acts as a link;" you'll have to be more specific.  Does it actually take you somewhere when you click there?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the space is inside the button or part of it. This will happen if you have set `padding` on your links or buttons. If you want to have space outside the buttons you will need to use `margin`. Or better, you can make your `links` container a flexbox and use `gap` property to create space between them.